# Error parsing rrule, dtstart is malformed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rfc2445

I am dealing with reoccurrences and using the google-rfc-2445 library

I have tried many different things at this point and it seems as though my DateTime variable is malformed and I am not sure what is happening.

The output looks like this `2015-05-05T17:11:11.000-05:00`
In the database it looks like this `2015-05-05 22:11:11.0`

The error I am getting looks like this

```
java.text.ParseException: cannot parse [[DTSTART=20150505T221111Z]] in [RRULE, recur]
```

I have tried formatting the output with no luck.

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

try{
    d = df.parse(event.getDtStart().toString());
    DateIterator date = DateIteratorFactory.createDateIterator("RRULE:" + event.getrRule(), d, TimeZone.getTimeZone(event.getTimeZone()), true);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think the problem is my DTStart is malformed but honestly at this point I have no idea.  It's formatting is odd.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue and its pretty silly.  So I am using [this library](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) for building the rrule on the front end with .js

The rrule that is being output looks like this. 
`'FREQ=MONTHLY;DTSTART=20000201T060000Z;INTERVAL=454;WKST=SU;BYHOUR=10;BYMINUTE=47;BYSECOND=5;BYDAY=TH'`

You CAN'T have dtstart inside the rrule.  So I removed and built it with this.

```
String rrule = event.getrRule().replaceAll("(DTSTART.*?;)","");
DateTimeIterator date2 = DateTimeIteratorFactory.createDateTimeIterator("RRULE:" + rrule, event.getDtStart(),DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(event.getTimeZone())), true);
```

and it works like a charm.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I have found that I am producing an extra day with this iterator.